# Updating alternating colored UITableViewCells when rows gets reordered or deleted

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm having a UITableView with alternating colored UITableViewCells. And the table can be edited: rows can be reordered and deleted. How do I update the cells alternating background color, when the rows get reordered or deleted?

I'm using this to draw the alternating colored cells:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath row] % 2) {
        // even row
        cell.backgroundColor = evenColor;
    } else {
        // odd row
        cell.backgroundColor = oddColor;
    }
}
```

But this method is not being called when a row gets reordered or deleted. And I can't call `[tableView reloadData]` from the following method, because it crashes the app in an infinite loop:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    // Move the object in the array
    id object = [[self.list objectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]] retain];
    [self.list removeObjectAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row]];
    [self.list insertObject:object atIndex:[toIndexPath row]];
    [object release];

    // Update the table ???
    [tableView reloadData]; // Crashes the app in an infinite loop!! 
}
```

Does anybody have a pointer or a best practices solution to deal with the issue of reordering alternating colored cells?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Used a delayed call to perform the reload if you can't call from that method:

```
[tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

It waits until after your current method is finished before it calls reload.

Answer (score 5):

No needs to use third-party objects or reload/refresh the whole dataSource. Just use the right tools in your swiss knife:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //1. remove your object
        [dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //2. update your UI accordingly
        [self.myTableView beginUpdates];
        [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [self.myTableView endUpdates];

        //3. obtain the whole cells (ie. the visible ones) influenced by changes
        NSArray *cellsNeedsUpdate = [myTableView visibleCells];
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(UITableViewCell *aCell in cellsNeedsUpdate) {
            [indexPaths addObject:[myTableView indexPathForCell:aCell]];
        }

        //4. ask your tableview to reload them (and only them)
        [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    }
}
```

Comment: `NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];` saves you from an unnecessary for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Reload is too heavyweight; I've written [AltTableViewController](http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2009/12/alternating-rows-for-uitableview/) that just changes background color of cells and it should work faster.

Answer (score 1):

I took all the UITableViewCell subviews from the tableview and sorted that array based on cells frame.origin.y so they were back in the proper order.  Then I looped through changing the background color based on the index == 0 || index % 2 == 0 re-coloring them.  Seems to work better than reloading the tableView as that was causing the animation to jerk. Worked for me at 1:25 AM

Answer (score 0):

[tableView reloadData] will get your table backgrounds back in the swing of things.  Your other option is to swap the background colors of the all visible cells from the indexPath of the lower index in the move on up to the highest in visibleCells.

Answer (score 0):

This works nice.  Start the pattern at the last index rather than the first.  That way each cell always retains it's background:

```
    if (dataSource.count - indexPath.row) % 2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```

I tried the other solutions, but wasn't completely satisfied.  This solution is not a hack and doesn't even add another line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using swift and NSFetchedResultsController:

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

    tableView.endUpdates()

    //for the alternate colours
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .fade)
}
```